"bei/in der Bank" and "an/in der Kasse"
I got two translations wrong on Duolingo in a matter of a few minutes, both with prepositions. I wonder if my versions, which were marked wrong by Duolingo, also work.

English original: Can I cash my check at the bank?
My translation: Kann ich meinen Scheck bei der Bank einlösen?
Duolingo's answer: Kann ich meinen Scheck in der Bank einlösen?

I am under the impression that when it comes to banks "in" and "bei" are both possible. A few discussions I have found online (1, 2) seem to corroborate that. I also found a lot of examples online of "bei einer Bank" (1, 2)

English prompt: You can buy the tickets at the ticket office.
My attempt: Sie können die Karten in der Kasse kaufen.
Duolingo's version: Sie können die Karten an der Kasse kaufen.

I used "in" in my translation, but on second thought a ticket office, unlike banks, doesn't seem to be a building which the customer enters and within the confines of which the transaction takes place. I guess it's more like a counter and that's why "an" is more appropriate in this case? If that is indeed the case, would "bei" also work here?

Sentence 1:
I clearly prefer "bei der Bank" here when talking about the institution as a functional entity where you can cash checks. When talking about the location, "in" comes into place:

"Wo finde ich den nächsten Geldautomaten?" - "In der Bank da drüben."

Sentence 2:
I think your interpretation is 100% correct. They think of the Kasse as a counter, that's why they use "an". If the ticket office is a building or shop, you could say in in a local sense, parallel to the bank example.
I can't really tell you why "bei" doesn't fit that well here, I think it's because we don't think of a ticket office as an institution like a bank or a post office. I wouldn't say "bei" wasn't possible at all, but "eine Eintrittskarte bei der Kasse kaufen" doesn't sound most natural to me. "Sie stand bei der Kasse und winkte ihm zu." in a narrower local sense ("next to") is completely fine though.

In your first sentence both versions are correct. "Bei der Bank" is treating the bank as an organisation rather than a place, "in der Bank" is the other way round and means rather the specific shop.
For instance:

Ich habe mein Konto bei der Sowieso-Bank.

You don't have your account at a certain branch office but rather at the organisation itself.

In der Bank ist die Beleuchtung schlecht.

We do talk about a certain branch office, otherwise it would hint to a certain organisational regulation to have bad lighting.
For the second sentence Duolingos version is more idiomatic. Yours is not wrong, but the ticket office is rather a certain place, so you do it "an der Kasse" - you walk up to the front of the counter, so you stand next to it - this is what "an" conveys. The ticket office is not a building, so "in" applies only for the clerk working it. If you can use "in" for places then you could use "into" (hinein) as well. Yes, "bei" would work too:

Ich kaufe mein Ticket bei der Kasse, nicht online.

But this is maybe idiomatic only in the southern regions of the German-speaking areas.
